# Moving xaml code behind to a view-model class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to load a `usercontrol` inside a `window` in WPF.

**MainWindow.XAML** (Simplified for sake of visibility)

```
<Window x:Class="CoffeeShop.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="700" Width="625">

   <Grid>
        <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,10,10" Name="orderTable" >
            <Grid>

            </Grid>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In the code-behind, I am creating an instance of that `usercontrol` and setting the `itemsSource` of a `datagrid` inside it. Loading my `userControl` inside the `contentControl` of my `xaml`page.

**MainWindow.XAML.cs**

```
            // OrderTable is my `userControl`
            OrderTable order = new CoffeeShop.OrderTable();
            order.PayButton.Click += OnPayButtonClicked;
            order.dataGrid1.ItemsSource = itemsList;
```

I have created a ViewModel class called `OrderViewModel` and the `OrderViewModel.cs` contains

```
namespace CoffeeShop.ViewModel
{
    class OrderViewModel
    {
        public Order OrdersViewModelProperty { get; set; }

        public OrderViewModel()
        {
            OrdersViewModelProperty = new Order();

            // Adopt the MVVM pattern ???
            // Bring the above code in the MainWindow.XAML.cs here ?
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is how to adopt this to a `MVVM` model ? Referred many tutorials but still feels a bit difficult to achieve this. Any pointers is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

```
<Window x:Class="dataTemplate.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content= "{Binding Path=MyOrderViewModelProperty}">
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:type local:OrderViewModel}">
                <view:UserControl1 />
                <DataTemplate/>
        </ContentControl>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I tried as per the pointer, but this is the error that is shown `the content is set more than once`.

Comment: Looks like you should read some articles about `DataBinding` and `Commands`. [This](http://www.wpftutorial.net/) site is not bad to get a first impression. Books like *WPF unleashed* and later *WPF pro* would be helpful. To get in touch with `MVVM` you can also read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) article.

Comment: Use something like Caliburn micro and the problem goes away.

Answer (score 1):

the easy answer: use DataTemplate, use Binding.

datatemplate for your viewmodel

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:type local:OrderViewModel}">
   <view:MyOrderViewWithDataGridAndSoOn />
 <DataTemplate/>
```

bind the instance of your orderviewmodel to the contentcontrol

```
 <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=MyOrderViewModelProperty}"/>
```

thats all. within your view you should use binding too. eg:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItemsListProperty}"/>
```

Comment: thank you. Giving that a try.

Comment: @blinmeis: kindly see my above edit. I am getting an error `the content is set more than once`.

Comment: you have to move the datatemplate to your resources. Window.Resources or ContentControl.Resources. and please follwo the comment from DHN, read the WPF unleashed book its very good.

Comment: Thank you. Amazoning the book.